# Form handler per bundle

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle different forms per bundle.
I current do something like:

```
class MyEntityForm extends ContentEntityForm {

  public function buildForm($form, $form_state) {

    $bundle = $this->entity->getType();

    switch ($bundle) {
      case 'bundle_a' :
        $form = BundleFormA::buildFormA($form,$form_state);
        break;
      case 'bundle_b' :
        $form = BundleFormB::buildFormB($form,$form_state);
        break;
    }
```

This works but I get errors with non-static $this which makes sense, but $this is available as far as I can tell.  Either way, I feel like I'm on the wrong path, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First option: The form class that needs to be used is linked to an action inside the form handlers array. You will need to define an action for each bundle. You will also need to define a route for each action/bundle.

Comment: Second option: create custom routing per each bundle and specify the _form property in the defaults array to the form class you require.

Comment: Third option: use a route subscriber service to alter the form routes and overwrite the _form property as you please.